# POST and PUT methods are not working in Postman but working in Swagger

Tags: json, postman

So the documentation is required from me on Postman. The problem is my APIs requires authentication so I can't use Swagger to test them. When I remove authorization from my controller and use Swagger it works, but using Postman it returns the following error.

[image: Error]

Postman headers for the request:

[image: Headers]

Comment: Could you also show what headers did you set for this request?

Comment: You can copy the curl from Swagger after executing in swagger and import the copied curl in postman. It will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set header Content-Type: application/json.

Comment: I can't edit the content of this field, I can neither edit nor delete nor paste a value in it

Comment: you can try "Bulk edit" button then, on your screenshot looks to be clickable.

Comment: @NourMawla you've selected "raw" as your input type. On the right of that you now see an orange "Text" if you click that you get a drop down that lets you select "JSON"

Answer (score 0):

Set header Content-Type: application/json.

[image: Check the Image for help]